# Trouble when I pass listbox values to another page on ASP:NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

Here is my code I would like to pass values of listbox(which is in home page) to textbox(which is in text box).However just first item of listbox goes, not all.

```
 protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                allItems += ListBox1.Items[i].ToString() + "--";
                allItems.Substring(0, 2);
                int m = allItems.Length - 2;
                string mmm = allItems.Substring(0, m);
                Response.Redirect("Statistics.aspx?ListBox1=" + mmm);
            }
        }
```

and this is from statistics page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox3.Text = Request.QueryString["ListBox1"];
        }
```

Comment: You should prefer to get values using Session, depends on data amount, if your list items has special characters etc. You can easily store ListBox to session and transfer it to another page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Response.Redirect("Statistics.aspx?ListBox1=" + mmm);
```

Move the above line outside of the loop.
You should only redirect once the loop has completed.

You will need to build the mm querystring value while looping thru the listbox items however.
Use a stringbuilder object.

Replace the line:

```
string mmm = allItems.Substring(0, m);
```

with

```
StringBuilder sbMMM = new StringBuilder();
MMM.append(allItems.Substring(0, m));
```

Don't declare the stringbuilder inside your loop. make sure that line is above the loop.

Edit the response.redirect to read like :

```
Response.Redirect("Statistics.aspx?ListBox1=" + sbMMM.ToString());
```

Comment: The name 'mmm' does not exist in the current context I got this error when i move it outside of the loop

Comment: Its declared inside the loop, that's why. Declare it at the top outside the loop
Put mmm = String.Empty; above the loop, then remove the word 'string' before mmm inside the loop..

Comment: But you need to use the stringbuilder like in my answer to build up the string before adding it to the querystring

Comment: I have made the changes; here is my code http://chopapp.com/#8i3534ixbut I got this errorRequest URL Too LongHTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long.

Comment: That link doesnt work. Theres a limit to what you can send on the querystring. If you've exceeded that limit than you will need to find an alternative method of sharing the data from page to page, but thats an entirely different qs.
Did you use the stringbuilder to build the querystring val? If so, put a breakpoint at the end of the loop and check what the stringbuilder contains.

Comment: If there are a lot of items in the listbox then its highly likely that if passing all of them on the queerystring in one go, then you will exceed the querystring limit.

Comment: Listbox contains a big matrix here in this code as yousee in home page ı am establishing a matrix then pass it to listbox from here it must go statistics.aspx page in to textbox http://pastie.org/10835429

Comment: sorry for the previous link this is the part of code where i try to pass listbox elements to textbox http://pastie.org/10835432

Comment: You need to see the value of sbMMM.ToString()); when you hit the redirect line (just before its executed). If its over 2000 chars in length then it is unlikely to work consistently on the querystring.
If that's the case, you either need to amend the data in the listbox or find another method of passing it between pages.
Sorry, but that's all the help I can give at this stage. If you like my answer please give it a vote.

Comment: Yes unfortunately there are more than 2000.Thanks for your help.I just would like to show the statistics(some lines,a matrice etc.) I have created another page for but maybe pop up or crystalreports would be more efficient for my problem.

Comment: No problem. If the listbox is populated from a file or db, why not just do the same for the textbox? Other options are to cache the data and retrieve it from there, or write it to the session.
Its more a design issue for you, have a good think about solutions first and foremost.

Comment: Please upvote my answer when you have a moment, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a problem.

once the loop jump